# Problema actualizando registros

Tags: php

Estoy probando un código que debería actualizar registros de una bd. Basicamente primero se recuperan los datos vía `GET` en un formulario y luego vía `POST` se recuperan los datos actualizados y se guardan en la bd con un `UPDATE`. El problema es que estoy recibiendo este error al actualizar:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
> access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'WHERE id=''' at line 8 in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\AWCP\secciones\empleados\editar.php:61 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\AWCP\secciones\empleados\editar.php(61):
> PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Proy\AWCP\secciones\empleados\editar.php on line 61

El codigo php es este:

```
    print_r($_GET['txtID']);//trato de ver si esta recibiendo txtID correctamente y si lo devuelve

if(isset($_GET['txtID'])){
    $txtID=(isset($_GET['txtID']))?$_GET['txtID']:"";
    $sentencia=$conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_empleados WHERE id=:id");
    $sentencia->bindParam(":id",$txtID);
    $sentencia->execute();  
    $registro=$sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);   
    $nombre=$registro["nombre"];
    $primerapellido=$registro["primerapellido"];

    
    $foto=$registro["foto"];
    $cv=$registro["cv"];
    
    $idpuesto=$registro["idpuesto"];
    $fechadeingreso=$registro["fechadeingreso"];
    
    $sentencia=$conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tbl_puestos`");
    $sentencia->execute();
    $lista_tbl_puestos=$sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
    
}


if($_POST){
    
    //recolectamos los datos del metodo POST
    $txtID=(isset($_POST["txtID"])?$_POST["txtID"]:"");
    $nombre=(isset($_POST["nombre"])?$_POST["nombre"]:"");
    $primerapellido=(isset($_POST["primerapellido"])?$_POST["primerapellido"]:"");    
    $idpuesto=(isset($_POST["idpuesto"])?$_POST["idpuesto"]:"");
    $fechadeingreso=(isset($_POST["fechadeingreso"])?$_POST["fechadeingreso"]:"");
    
    //Preparar la insercion de los datos
    $sentencia=$conexion->prepare("
    UPDATE tbl_empleados SET
        nombre=:nombre, 
        primerapellido=:primerapellido,
        idpuesto=:idpuesto,
        fechadeingreso=:fechadeingreso,
    WHERE id=:id
    ");
   
    //Asignando los valores que vienen del metodo POST (los que vienen del formulario)
    $sentencia->bindParam(":nombre",$nombre);
    $sentencia->bindParam(":primerapellido",$primerapellido);
    $sentencia->bindParam(":idpuesto",$idpuesto);
    $sentencia->bindParam(":fechadeingreso",$fechadeingreso);  
    $sentencia->bindParam(":id",$txtID); 
    $sentencia->execute(); 
        
    $foto=(isset($_FILES["foto"]['name'])?$_FILES["foto"]['name']:"");
    $cv=(isset($_FILES["cv"]['name'])?$_FILES["cv"]['name']:"");
        
    //header("Location:index.php");
    
}
```

He revisado todas las variables y en especial `$txtID`, puesto que se menciona en el error, pero a mi parecer eso esta correcto. También hice un `print_r($_GET['txtID'])` para saber si recibía correctamente ese valor y veo que lo recibe. ¿Dónde podría estar el error?

Comment: La coma antes del WHERE está demás...

Comment: Es cierto, gracias

Comment: Ahora no sale el error pero "tbl_empleados" no se está actualizando. ¿Por qué sería?

Comment: ¿Se están _commiteando_ los cambios?

Comment: El boton de actualizar es de tipo "submit" si es a lo que te refieres: <button type="submit" >Actualizar registro</button> Una vez presionado la el formulario conserva los cambios pero no se refleja en la bd y cuando vuelvo de nuevo a la página los cambios se han perdido.

Comment: No, no me refería a eso. Las inserciones/actualizaciones/eliminaciones se realizan a través de transacciones, y puede que los cambios no se estén _commiteando_ en la base de datos. Puede que tu base de datos no tenga configurado el _autocommit_ (que no está mal que esté así, así si ocurrió un error se hace un _rollback_ y listo). Al no hacer _commit_, todo cambio que hayas hecho se revierte. No olvides probar primeramente si ese `UPDATE` funciona desde tu administrador de base de datos (phpmyadmin, dbeaver, etc.)

Comment: Estoy probando el comando UPDATE en phpmyadmin y funciona correctamente en esa tabla. Puede que sea otra cosa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posiblemente el error sea que la variable `$nombre` no lo defines para recolectar los datos del POST al igual que las demás, ya que aquí requieres de la variable `$nombre` en la primera `$sentencia`:

```
$sentencia->bindParam(":nombre",$nombre);
$sentencia->bindParam(":primerapellido",$primerapellido);
$sentencia->bindParam(":idpuesto",$idpuesto);
$sentencia->bindParam(":fechadeingreso",$fechadeingreso);  
$sentencia->bindParam(":id",$txtID);
```

Por lo que también debes inicializarlo:

```
$nombre=(isset($_POST["nombre"])?$_POST["nombre"]:"");
```

O usar la variable `$primernombre` en la primera `$sentencia`:

```
$sentencia->bindParam(":nombre",$primernombre);
```

Comment: Tienes razón, esa parte la escribí mal (ya está corregido) pero no es lo que está provocando que la UPDATE no funcione ya que sigue sin actualizar la bd. El error está en otra parte pero gracias por mostrar ese detalle.

Comment: Puedes visualizar el error con `$error = $sentencia->errorInfo();` y luego `print_r($error);`, me dices que te sale.

Comment: Ok, me sale al poner eso y actualizar: Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

Comment: Pues no tienes ningún error... el error puede estar en otra parte... Haz un echo a tus variables `$nombre`, `$primernombre`, etc... a ver si no vienen vacías.

Comment: Le hice un "print_r($variable);" a todas y salen correctas excepto $txtID. Finalmente ví que el POST no estaba recibiendo esta variable que debería estar en el formulario pero no estaba. Añadiendo ese dato al formulario ahora si recibe correctamente y actualiza también correctamente. Gracias a todos por la ayuda

Comment: Me alegro saber que lo solucionaste, si deseas puedes verificar mi respuesta para que tu pregunta esté como respondida, saludos